# How to fetch documents with must match clause in elastic search 8.9 v

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
             {
                 "match": {
                     "cid": {
                         "query": "AFM"
                     }
                 }
             },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "web_code": "P" // how to write multiple codes here
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
 }
```

The above is working fine for a single value. How to fetch with multiple web codes using must syntax..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `terms` query instead of `match`:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "web_code.keyword": ["P", "R", "S", "T"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: i did go the results from match of webcode:"p" but if i use the terms webcode:["p"] did not got results.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `web_code` field?

Comment: "web_code": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: Ok, you need to use the keyword sub-field, I've revised my query

Comment: It worked. Thanks Val. What is the correlation of keyword with web_code

Comment: Glad it helped! it's just a sub-field of type keyword which indexes the exact values (i.e. not analyzed) that you can then query using `terms`