# Elasticsearch 8.9 version error: [match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to get my Elasticsearh query to work, but I get this error:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: [match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]
```

This is my query:

```
{
    "size": 25,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": [
        {
            "r_date.keyword": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "c_id": {
                            "query": ["TSM"]//it should accept multiple values
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "sec": {
                            "query": 
                                "500"
                            
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "r_date": {
                            "gte": "02/28/2023",
                            "lte": "08/29/2023",
                            "format": "MM/dd/yyyy"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you receive the same error in case of using a short match syntax, like: {"match":{"c_id":"TSM"} ?

Comment: I am getting issues while passing multiple values  in array.

Comment: You already asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948090/how-to-fetch-documents-with-must-match-clause-in-elastic-search-8-9-v) I answered it and you accepted it (hint: match doesn't accept an array)

Comment: You also probably overlooked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76956424/4604579) which indicates that `match` doesn't take arrays as input but simply a string of text.

Comment: how to receive multiple strings in an array?

Comment: I wanted to have the syntax when i receive more than one string should be able to work also.